# Jensen inequality variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In a probability space we have Jensen's inequality which states that for a convex function $f$ on the real line we have that 
$$ f ( \int_\Omega g d\mu) \leq \int_\Omega f \circ g d\mu$$

In the real line we can also renormalise and say that

$$ f ( \int_a^b g dx) \leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f ((b-a)g) dx$$

My first question is: Can we generalise this idea to the measure theoretic setting if $\mu(\Omega)$ is not $1$ but still finite? I would conjecture this, is it true?

$$ f ( \int_\Omega g d\mu) \leq \frac{1}{\mu(\Omega)}\int_\Omega f(\mu(\Omega) g) d\mu$$

My second question is, do we need $f$ to be convex on the real line, or just at the points we consider it? For example, take $x^3$ that is convex on the positive half line and concave in the negative one. For a positive $g$ can we still say the following?

$$\left( \int_\Omega g d\mu \right)^3 \leq \int_\Omega g^3 d\mu $$

Comment: Pages 14-15: http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~lerdos/WS07/FA/leb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu$ is finite and nonzero on space $X$, then clearly $\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\mu$ is a probability measure. So the obvious generalization is:

$$f\left(\int_X g(x)\frac{1}{\mu(X)}d\mu\right)\leq \int_X f(g(x))\frac{1}{\mu(X)}d\mu.$$

The answer to your second question is yes.